# Unable to generate gcda files in cross-profile environment

Tags: gcov

Trying to run `gcov`, by building source code in an environment different from run environment. I have built source code with `--coverage` option.
To ensure that if I run

```
strings -a binary| grep gcda
```

I am able to see some `gcda` files. But when I deploy rpm in docker container and run the testcase I don't see `.gcda` files getting generated.

I have added `GCOV_PREFIX` and `GCOV_PREFIX_STRIP` variables.

Comment: gcda files are result of a function call to gcov_dump or gcov_flush. How do you invoke the gcov_flush function?

Comment: i restart the process in docker container to get the gcda files